# How to use different coding styles between the actual code and the code displayed in VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

My friend is currently contributing to the OSS project in C#. The project uses the [BSD/Allman coding style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style), commonly used in C#, but my friend prefers the [Java style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_Java) for religious reasons.
He says the unfamiliar style is painful for him, takes away most of his thinking power, and prevents him from coding as much as he would like. (He says that "*transpiling*" takes up too much of his brain resources.)

So I came up with the idea of applying a customized coding style only to the editor display in VSCode, converting only the show to the user's desired coding style when saving, on the other hand, converting the coding style to the repository-specified coding style when saving.

I think there is demand besides him for this, but are there any extensions that fulfill such a requirement?
Also, please let us know if you have any other good ideas, not limited to this approach.

Comment: The C# extension for VS Code allows to format the code via CTRL + K, CTRL + F. 
So he could atleast write in his own style and, before commiting, format the code.
Or you could teach your friend how to work in a team...

Comment: Okay, that is undoubtedly a great idea. Can we also compare the diff between commits with “local” coding style standards?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. If you want to be able to format the whole project so it adheres to your code style, you can use a tool like **CSharpier**. 
There you can set your specific coding style rules, run it in command line, configure it to run in a pre-commit-hook and all fun stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the project in question is on a modern .Net version, the correct tool for this kind of work is the `dotnet format` CLI tool.

If the project doesn't already have one, you could submit a `.editorconfig` file to the project enforcing their style rules. Your friend could then create a personal version of this file with his own rules.

Some of the relevant rules for formatting C# code are documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options